# Button Disable Validation is not working on keyup in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Hi i have a form i want to validate the field for this i am using `jquery` now 
the first field `name` validation is working fine it disabled the button untill phone field is empty. After that in second field the numeric condition is fine but the problem is it isn't checking the first field is empty. Means the condition become true without checking first field is empty or not. Hope i am able to understand you all what my problem is

**jQuery Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     setTimeout(function(){
                $('#sfp_Modal').modal('show');
            }, 3000);
    /*
    $( ".sfpsubmit, .close" ).click(function() {
        var sfp_cookie = $.cookie('SFPopup', 'sf_popup', { expires: 7 });
        alert(sfp_cookie);          
        if(sfp_cookie == null){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#sfp_Modal').modal('show');
            }, 3000);
        }else{          
                $('#sfp_Modal').modal('hide');
        }
    }); */

        $( "#sf-popup .sfname" ).keyup(function() {
          if($(this).val() == '' || $( "#sf-popup .sfphone").val() == '' || $.isNumeric(sfp_phone) == true){
                $('#sfpsubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');

            } else{
                $('#sfpsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
                $( ".sfp_btn" ).click(function() {
                    $('#sfp_Modal').modal('hide');
                });
            }
        });

        $( "#sf-popup .sfphone" ).keyup(function() {
            var sfp_phone = $(this).val();              
            if(sfp_phone.length > 10){
                $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,10));
                $('#sfpsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');

            }   

                if(sfp_phone == '' || $( "#sf-popup .sfname").val() == '' || $.isNumeric(sfp_phone) == false ||  sfp_phone.length < 10){
                $('#sfpsubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');

            } else{
                $('#sfpsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
                $( ".sfp_btn" ).click(function() {
                    $('#sfp_Modal').modal('hide');
                });
            }
            });

        $( "#sf-popup .sfemail" ).keyup(function() {    
                var $email = this.value;
                validateEmail($email);

                function validateEmail(email) {
                    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                    if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
                        $('#sfpsubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('#sfpsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
                }   
                }); 

    });
```

**My form**

```
echo "<form method='post' action='' name='sfp_popup' id='sf-popup' >";
    echo "<input type='text' name='sf_name' id='sf_name' placeholder='Name' class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 sfname'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='sf_phone' id='sf_phone' placeholder='98765-43210' class='col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 sfphone'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='sf_email' id='sf_email' placeholder='noreply@example.com' class='col-md-12 sfemail'>";
    echo "<textarea name='sf_message' id='sf_message' placeholder='Enter Your Query' class='col-md-12'></textarea>";
    echo "</form>";     
    echo "<button id='sfpsubmit' class='btn btn-primary sfp_btn' name='sfpsubmit' disabled>Submit</button>";
```

Comment: why cant you use on blur?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel?... use [Jquery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: Sorry but i am not that good in `jquery`

Comment: and one more thing i am not assigning the submit button inside form

Comment: Hi @KAD thanks for you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have validate my form using [validate.js](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js) . Here is the `jQuery` code for validation. Thanks for help

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#sf-popup").validate({

                    rules: {                        
                        sf_name:{
                            required:true,
                            minlength:3,
                            maxlength:30,
                            digits: false
                        },
                        sf_phone:{
                            required:true,
                            maxlength:10,
                            digits: true

                        },
                        sf_email:{
                            required:true,
                            email:true
                        },
                        sf_message:"required"

                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        // Append error within linked label
                        jQuery( element )
                            .closest( "#sf-popup" )
                                .find( "label[for='" + element.attr( "id" ) + "']" )
                                    .append( error );
                    },
                    errorElement: "span",
                    messages: {
                        sf_name:{
                            required : "Please enter your Name",
                            minlength : "Minimum Length Should be 3",
                            maxlength : "Max Length Should be 30",
                            digits : "Use Characters only"
                            },
                        sf_phone:{
                            required : "Please enter Phone number",
                            maxlength : "Max length should be 10",
                            digits : "Phone number is not valid"
                            },
                        sf_email:{
                            required : "Please enter email",
                            email : "please enter valid E-mail"
                            },
                        sf_message:"Please enter message"   
                    },
                    submitHandler: function() {

                            var sfp_cookie = jQuery.cookie('SFPopup', 'sf_popup', { expires: 7 });

                            setTimeout(function(){
                                if(jQuery.cookie('SFPopup') == null){
                                    jQuery('#sfp_Modal').modal('show');
                                }else{          
                                jQuery('#sfp_Modal').modal('hide');
                                }
                                }, 3000); 

                            var name = jQuery("#sf_name").val();
                            var phone = jQuery("#sf_phone").val();
                            var email = jQuery("#sf_email").val();
                            var message = jQuery("#sf_message").val();

                            jQuery.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: sfpAjax.ajaxurl,
                                data: {action: "sfp_insert","sf_name":name,"sf_phone":phone,"sf_email":email,"sf_message":message}
                            });

                    }


                });

});
```